# Python: Regular Expression only works on directories with 1 file in

Tags: python, regex

I have the following function which uses a RE:

```
def friendSearch():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/myFiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in files:
        inputFile = open(x, "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()
        match = re.search(r'(?<="NAME":)("[^"]+")',content)
    print (match)
```

It works fine when the file containing the string is in a directory on its own, but when other files are added to the directory it returns nothing.

Is this because "match" is over written with each file that is processed? If so how can I stop this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the issue is `match` being written over with each file.  I am assuming you want a single list with all of the matches from each file, so instead of doing `match = ...` use `matches.extend(...)` and initialize `matches` to an empty list before your loop.

For example:

```
def friendSearch():
    matches = []
    os.chdir("C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Files")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    for x in files:
        inputFile = open(x, "r")
        try:
            content = inputFile.read()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue
        inputFile.close()
        matches.extend(re.findall(r'(?<="text":)("[^"]+")',content))
    print (matches)
```

Comment: I'd rename `match` to `matches`, following the usual convetion of having plural names for sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Your `match` will contain search results from the very last file only.  This line:

```
match = re.findall(r'(?<="text":)("[^"]+")',content)
```

discards what was in `match` before it.  Try this:

```
match = []
for x in files:
  inputFile = open (x, "r")
  try:
    content = inputFile.read()
  except UnicodeDecodeError:
    continue
  inputFile.close ()
  match = match + re.findall (r'(?<="text":)("[^"]+")', content)
```

Comment: so its what I thought, how can i change that?